# Creating borders while using pygame.key.get_pressed()

Tags: python, pygame

I am coding a top-down shooter game, and was recently trying to figure out a way to continuously move my character while holding down a key. I was searching the internet to find a way, and found `pygame.key.get_pressed()`, this worked great until I tried to create borders so you couldn't escape the sides of the screen. I have basically worked out the problem being while your holding down the movement keys, pygame can't check the x and y coordinates of your player, therefore it allows the player to move out of bounds even when you add something like `if x >= 0:`.

I am asking if there is a way to create a border for the sides of the screen, while holding down a movement button with `pygame.key.get_pressed()`, or if there is a good alternative for moving.

Some of the code :

```
    if eventHandler == "LEVEL1":
        # SEE IF PLAYER QUIT AND PROCEED TO QUIT
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                loop = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

                if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                    movingUP = True
                if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                    movingDOWN = True
                if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    movingLEFT = True
                if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                    movingRIGHT = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                movingUP = False
                movingDOWN = False
                movingLEFT = False
                movingRIGHT = False
                x_change = 0
                y_change = 0

            if movingUP == True:
                y_change -= 5 
            if movingDOWN == True:
                y_change += 5
            if movingLEFT == True:
                x_change -= 5
            if movingRIGHT == True:
                x_change += 5

    # UPDATES EVERY TIME GAME LOOPS
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
    x += x_change
    y += y_change
    if eventHandler == "LEVEL1":
        w.blit(level1map, (0, 0))
        w.blit(player, (x, y))
        pygame.display.update()
```

I have already tried adding (with 16 being the border)

```
if x >= 16:
    x_change = 0
    movingLEFT = 0
```

and so on with all of the directions. I tried this for basically anywhere it would make sense in the code. I have also tried putting

```
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x >= 16:
    movingLEFT = True
```

"and variable >= border" everywhere it might make a border, but still no results.

Any way to create a border that works or an alternative for moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] while your holding down the movement keys, pygame can't check the x and y coordinates of your player, [...]

No.

While your holding down the movement keys, no event occurs. There is a single `pygame.KEYDOWN` event when the key is pressed and a single `pygame.KEYUP` event when the key is released.
But there are no continuously events, when a key is pressed.

It is perfect suitable to get the pressed key in the event loop by ([`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed)) and to change the state of the control variables `movingUP`, `movingDOWN`, `movingLEFT` `movingRIGHT`. The values which are returned by `pygame.key.get_pressed()` are updated when the event is handled by [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).

But the *bounds* check has to be done in every frame, every time when the position (`x`, `y`) was changed. It has to bed done in the main game loop, rather than the event loop:

```py
maxX = # screenWidth - playerWidth  
maxY = # screenHeight - playerHeight 

while loop:
    if eventHandler == "LEVEL1":
        # SEE IF PLAYER QUIT AND PROCEED TO QUIT
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                loop = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                movingUP = True
            # [...]

        if movingUP == True:
            y_change -= 5 
        # [...]

x += x_change
y += y_change

if x < 0:
    x = 0
    x_change = 0
elif x > maxX
    x = maxX
    x_change = 0
if y < 0:
    y = 0
    y_change = 0
elif y > maxY
    y = maxY
    y_change = 0
```